# HTML link to TLD

Tags: html

Is there a way to link to the top level domain (TLD) with plain HTML?

```
<a href="{magic}/">Go to TLD</a>
```

Imagine I am on `http://subdomain.example.com/subfolder`.
Now all I have to do to jump to the root *folder* is using `/` as `href` attribute - fine.

But what if I want to jump to `http://example.com` not `http://subdomain.example.com`?

or even better:

from `http://subdomain.example.com/subfolder` to `http://example.com/subfolder` (same subfolder)?

Sure I could do this in JavaScript like this:

```js
var urlParts = location.hostname.split('.');
var tld = urlParts.slice(-2).join('.');

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = '//' + tld;
a.innerHTML = "Go to TLD";

var a2 = document.createElement('a');
a2.href = '//' + tld + window.location.pathname;
a2.innerHTML = "Go to same folder on TLD";

document.body.appendChild(a);
document.body.appendChild(a2);
```

But isn't there any other way?

Comment: You can always use regex if you don't like your current method.

Comment: Not possible. If you want to change the hostname, you have to use an absolute `http://new.host.name.example.com` url. **WITHOUT** the `http://hostname.com` portion, ALL urls will be intrepreted as local/relative within the same site only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now this is not possible without parsing the URL and outputting it. There's no standard similar to `../` (going up a folder) that'd allow "jumping up" one domain level. For a different JS-based solution, you could go for a simpler regex approach, but checking whether you can go up one level or not can be tricky (eg. `example.co.uk` would turn into `co.uk`). Here's the regex approach nonetheless:

```js
var hostname = 'test.example.com'; //location.hostname
var tld = hostname.replace(/^.*\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$/,'$1');
document.write(tld);
```